# Error 404 Not Found /localhost:8080/MyApp/proxy/pagingmemory.js

Tags: extjs

So I'm getting this 404 error from my console:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/MyApp/proxy/pagingmemory.js?_dc=1394636131603"
```

Here are my Ext.Loader configs:

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: true,
    paths: {
        'Ext.grid'  : 'extjs/src/grid',
        'Ext.ux'    : 'extjs/examples/ux'
    }
});

Ext.require([
    'Ext.ux.PagingMemoryProxy',
    'Ext.ux.form.ItemSelector', 
    'Ext.grid.plugin.RowExpander', 
    'Ext.grid.*', 
    'Ext.data.*',  
    'Ext.selection.CheckboxModel',
    'Ext.toolbar.Paging'

]);
```

I only get an error when I try to specify the `pagingmemory` proxy on my store:

```
var newstore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    autoLoad    : true,
    pageSize    : 5,
    proxy:{
        type: 'pagingmemory'// Here 
    }//etc.
```

PagingMemoryProxy creates an alias, `proxy.pagingmemory`, but it seems that ExtJS is looking for a `pagingmemory.js` file. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Weird. Have you tried to attach the proxy to the Model? And can you prove that PagingMemoryProxy.js gets loaded?

Comment: I haven't tried attaching the proxy to the Model, and I put an alert at the top of PagingMemoryProxy.js which does fired while the page loads

Comment: Did you try defining the type `type:"proxy.pagingmemory"`, does that make a difference?

Comment: I have, but then i get at 404 on `http://localhost:8080/MyApp/proxy/proxy/pagingmemory.js?_dc=1394714696063`